# Hiding a system menu item in ExtJS

Tags: extjs, air

I have the following code

```
var menus = Ext.air.SystemMenu;

    menus.add('File', [
        actions.newTask, 
        actions.newList, 
        actions.newFolder, 
        '-',{
            text:'Import...',
            handler: function(){
                var importer = new tx.Importer();
                importer.doImport(function(){
                    tx.data.lists.load();
                    root.reload();
                    loadList('root');
                    Ext.Msg.hide();
                });
            }
        },{
            text:'Export...',
            handler: function(){
                new tx.Exporter();
            }
        },
        '-', 
        actions.quit
    ]);
```

and i want to hide the 'Import' item.I have been to the API for version 3.3.0 and there is no hide method for Ext.air.SystemMenu class.How should i hide it?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give your import menu button an ID:

```
{
     text:'Import...',
     id: 'importBtn',
     handler: function(){
         var importer = new tx.Importer();
         importer.doImport(function(){
             tx.data.lists.load();
             root.reload();
             loadList('root');
             Ext.Msg.hide();
         });
     }
}
```

In the source code there is a method for visbility (which just disables the button):

```
 setVisible : function(v){
    // could not find way to hide in air so disable?
    nativeItem.enabled = !v;
 },
```

So you just have to call this method on the button:

```
Ext.getCmp('importBtn').setVisible(false);
```

Looks like it doesn't provide a method for completely hiding it though, as the setVisible method only disables it.

Comment: in the api i found this method disable: true or false

Comment: yeah, you can use that config option on a button to render the button disabled, but if you want to change it after it has been rendered then use the code above